# How to find something without replacing it

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I would like to use the atom find and replace function to change the lines in a project like

```
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
```

into

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
```

so I did a regex :

```
(var|let)\s?\w+\s?\=\s?require
```

And I put in the replace function

```
const $2 = require
```

But I dont want to type again "require" in the replace and I don't know how to not capture it in the find function. 
I tried the find

```
(var|let)(?:\s?\w+\s?\=\s?require)
```

But it finds the line and wants to replace it

Comment: Try with a lookahead - `(var|let)\s?(\w+)\s?\=\s?(?=require)` (I also put `'w+` into a group so that `$2` could "work")

Comment: Damned... I tried it yesterday but somehow, it works now... I think i did a mistake, thanks :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookahead, `(?=require)`:

```
(var|let)\s?(\w+)\s?\=\s?(?=require)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After matching an optional whitespace after `=`, the lookahead will assert the presence of `require` substring, and if it is missing, the match will fail.

Note that in order for the `$2` to get filled, you need to wrap `\w+` with a capturing group.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IKOaDx/1).

**Details**

- `(var|let)` - Group 1: `var`or `let` substrings
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `\s?\=\s?` - a `=` enclosed with 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `(?=require)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of `require` immediately to the left of the current location.

Comment: To use minimum char in the replace function I think

    (var|let)(?=\s?(\w+)\s?\=\s?require)

is the optimal one

Comment: @Leyffda If you do not want to insert spaces between `=`, yes, that is OK.